# Где хранить данные VSIX?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, manifest

Есть у меня `VSIX`-расширение, которое в процессе работы может генерировать файлы с пользовательским контентом

Я решил, что файлы эти буду хранить в папке с расширением

Но вот беда - я сейчас обнаружил, что при обновлении папка расширения полностью **удаляется**, хотя я думал, что **обновляются** лишь существующие файлы...

То есть при обновлении пользователи будут терять все данные, которые ранее были сохранены, что, мягко говоря, неправильно

Так что мне в срочном порядке нужно выпустить обновление, которое поменяет дислокацию пользовательских файлов, чтобы те не страдали от будущих обновлений

---

**Где** правильно хранить некоторые данные пользователей, созданные посредством `VSIX` расширения?

И

**Возможно ли** поменять конфигурацию обновления расширения таким образом, чтобы все его файлы не удалялись, а обновлялись лишь уже существующие, и **как** это сделать?

Comment: Если из расширений есть доступ к AppData или "Мои документы", то видимо в них, как и в обычных программах.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight проблема в том, что если пользователь реально захочет удалить мое расширение, то файлы, сохранённые в иных каталогах, зависнут мертвым грузом...

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, хотя... это все же меньшее зло, чем удаление важных файлов хД